# LWC Issue Using CSS in Apex-generated HTML String

Tags: lightning-web-components, css

I am generating an HTML string for a table using Apex then passing that into a lightning web component using the @wire decorator. In my HTML file, I am using:

`<lightning-formatted-rich-text value={chart.data}></lightning-formatted-rich-text>`

to unescape the HTML characters. However, styles from the LWC's .css file are not being applied.

For example, if I simply hard code in the LWC .html file:

`<table class="myclass" ... </table>`

the CSS is correctly applied. But if I pass this code in from Apex the styling for myclass will not be applied.

Comment: I believe that injecting the HTML into a `lightning-formatted-rich-text` component will make that markup a part of that component and it will not be accessible by CSS in the parent. You may have to use `style` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the community. I think nbrown is right, I also couldn't reach the content of `lightning-formatted-rich-text` using the CSS file.

Looking at the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-formatted-rich-text/documentation) it appears that Salesforce are using inline-styling in their examples as well `richtext = "<h2 style=\"text-align: center\">Default <s>Value</s></h2>";`. So that can be one option for you.

Another option could be the use of `lwc:dom=manual`.

> Add this directive to a native HTML element to call appendChild() on
>   the element from the owner’s JavaScript class and preserve styling.

Check this [playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/8hNIH41Du/7/edit) to see an example. I believe that approach can work for your scenario. However you should be wary that there are certain limitations when using `lwc:dom=manual` on a native HTML element.

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily resolve this issue of styling by using the directive `lwc:dom="manual"` on your element. No need to use the richtext component.

We had a similar issue in the past where css classes was not being applied.
Here is a sample code:

```
<div lwc:dom="manual">{{generatedHTML}}</div>
```

Here's the definition of `lwc:dom="manual"` as per Salesforce documentation:

Add this directive to a native HTML element to call appendChild() on the element from the owner’s JavaScript class and preserve styling.